# Editing hidden form field with Jquery in Drupal

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, drupal, hidden

Currently I'm trying to edit a hidden form with the command:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){    
    jQuery("#test").val("hi");
 });
```

This is inside an inline drupal_add_js.

When the form 'test' is a normal textfield, this works. When it is hidden, this does not work. I'm currently using Drupal 7's webform module to create the form. I've read dozens of stackoverflow questions regarding populating hidden fields but I haven't gotten anything to work. I'm hoping that its just something that is syntactically different for hidden fields, but most likely its something in drupal I don't know about.

Comment: when are you calling that statement?

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function(){    
   jQuery("#edit-submitted-test").val("hi").fadeIn("slow");
  }); Sorry, I dont know how to format these comments correctly.

Comment: you cant. add you full code with formatting to the question

Comment: If you inspect your page with Firebug, are you able to see the Javascript code that you added with `drupal_add_js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try instead:

```
jQuery("input[name=test]").val("hi");
```

Comment: Turned out to be jQuery('[name="submitted[test]"]').val("hi"); This lead me on the right track, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

i am really not aware of coding style in `Drupal`, but if u want i can suggest you in basic jQuery way, hope this will b helpful for u :)

### HTML

```
<form name="testform" method="POST" action ="#">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenInput" id="hiddenInput">
    Hii
    <input type="submit" name="Go" >
</form>
```

### jQuery

```
$('form').submit{(
    alert('Submitted');
    var hid=$('input[type="hidden"]').val('HiddenText');
    alert(hid.val);
    return false;
    });
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7JVT6/1/)